# How to stop and play new songs in mediaplayer in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-listview, android-mediaplayer

I have a `listview` of all musics in the phone. Whenever user click on the item of the `listview` it starts a same activity of my player class every time. The first music chosen by user plays great. But the problem is when user choose the second music, it starts play new one without stopping previous one. So the result is two musics playing together.

This is my `listview` `onItemClickListener()`

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                String songId = tv.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), player.class);
                i.putExtra("id", songId);

                startActivity(i);
            }
});
```

and the main portion of my player class:

```
private MediaPlayer mp;


Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String songId = null;
if(extras != null){
      songId = extras.getString("id");
      play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
}

find(songId);

private void find(String songName) {
        for(int t = 0; t < songs.size(); t++){
            if(("" + songs.get(t)).endsWith(songName)){   //songs, an ArrayList of music files path
                Uri myUri = Uri.parse("" + songs.get(t));
                stopPlaying();
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, myUri);
                mp.start();
                break;
            }
        }
}

private void stopPlaying() {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
    }
```

I have tried a several way to get rid of this problem. But I din't understand what I am missing. I can provide full code if needed.

Comment: Add your complete code please :-)

Comment: @Xry http://pastebin.com/7G70imeV

Answer (score 0):

Since you have called stopPlaying method, ideally it should stop. Try adding this line of code

`mp.setLooping(false);` before `mp.start();`

Not sure if this would fix the issue.

Also Try this

```
 if(mp!=null && mp.isPlaying())
```

instead of

```
if (mp != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to previous answer

Define your media player as static

static MediaPlayer mp;